# function that returns data from an observableArray in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

this is the case...

i have a query with this format

```
{
    query:'A query string',
    user: 'email@user.com.ar',
}
```

in my view model i have a list of users and a function

```
var self=this;
self.queries=ko.observableArray(
[
    {
        query:'A query string',
        user: 'email@user.com.ar',
    }
]);
self.users=ko.observableArray(
[
    {user:'email@user.com.ar',data_of_user:{name:'User Name'}}
])
self.getUserInfo=function(email)
{
    var data_user=_.findWhere(self.users(),{email:email});
    return data_user.data_of_user.name;
}
```

but didnt work

how can i do this but with other approach??

i need to create a span that can pass the email of the user and get the name

```
<div data-bind="foreach:queries">
    <span data-bind="text:$root.getUserInfo.bind($data,$data.email)">
<div/>
```

Comment: this is the result of the span text: function () { [native code] }

Comment: Do you want crete an input to edit the user Email ?

Comment: Please share more view and view model.

Comment: nop, i want to show a span that contains the name of the user, and the name of the user is inside data_of_user['name'], but the queries only have the email of the user, all the data is inside self.users

Answer (score 1):

There were some erros I fxed.

View :

```
<div data-bind="foreach:queries">
    <div data-bind="with: ($root.getUserInfo($data))">
        <!-- user context -->
        <span data-bind="text: email"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: data_of_user.name"></span>      
   </div>
<div/>
```

JS :

```
var VM = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.queries = ko.observableArray(
    [{
        query: 'A query string',
        email: 'email@user.com.ar',
    }]);
    self.users = ko.observableArray(
    [{
        email: 'email@user.com.ar',
        data_of_user: {
            name: 'User Name'
        }
    }])
    self.getUserInfo = function (user) {
        var user = _.findWhere(self.users(), {
            'email': user.email
        });
        return user;
    }
    ;
};
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

**[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bGRA7/)**

Comment: this works great! thank you for your time, and your experience